# I want to find a way to c# CopyToAsync source code Link;

Tags: c#, .net, stream

I want to find a way to c# :

```cs
public System.Threading.Tasks.Task CopyToAsync (System.IO.Stream destination,  System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken);
```

source code link.

The reason is that when I use the following code in Asp.NET Core 6.0:

```cs
namespace Magicodes.ExporterAndImporter.Excel.AspNetCore
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 基类
    /// </summary>
    public class XlsxFileResultBase : ActionResult
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// 下载Excel文件
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="context"></param>
        /// <param name="stream"></param>
        /// <param name="downloadFileName"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        protected virtual async Task DownloadExcelFileAsync(ActionContext context,
                                                            Stream stream,
                                                            string downloadFileName)
        {
            var response = context.HttpContext.Response;
            response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";

            if (downloadFileName == null)
            {
                downloadFileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N") + ".xlsx";
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Path.GetExtension(downloadFileName)))
            {
                downloadFileName += ".xlsx";
            }

            context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", new[] {
                "attachment; filename=" +HttpUtility.UrlEncode(downloadFileName)
            });
            await stream.CopyToAsync(context.HttpContext.Response.Body);
        }
    }
}
```

But I don't know if the stream should be released. Before I stream this method, I used a MemoryStream with the using declaration. But this program reports an error and tells me:

> 错误消息: Cannot access a closed Stream.
> 堆栈信息: at System.IO.MemoryStream.CopyToAsync(Stream destination, Int32 bufferSize, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

I wondered if this Stream would be automatically released in ASP.NET Core, and wanted to find the source code as my rationale.

Asp.NET Core 6.0 returns file streams

Comment: My opinion is, in this case you get the stream as a parameter and it is therefore not your responsibility to close it.

Comment: Here is [the method](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/IO/Stream.cs#L87). As Jeroen says, it isn't really that method's responsibility to dispose the stream. That should generally be the stream's owner, wherever that is.